RStudio keyboard change?
The keyboard shortcuts in R Studio changed and I'm not sure what I did.
Option + "-" is no longer <- but =, which are both technically assignment operators so doesn't affect the code. But it feels off...
And commenting a segment with shift + cmd is  and not #.
Also, a new line no longer indents as indicated in the global options.
How can I revert back to the way it was before?
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 14.4.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] skimr_2.1.4      lubridate_1.9.0  timechange_0.1.1 janitor_2.1.0    magrittr_2.0.3   forcats_0.5.2   
 [7] stringr_1.4.1    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1      readr_2.1.3      tidyr_1.2.1      tibble_3.2.1    
[13] ggplot2_3.3.6    tidyverse_1.3.2  rio_0.5.29       here_1.0.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9          assertthat_0.2.1    rprojroot_2.0.3     digest_0.6.30       utf8_1.2.2         
 [6] repr_1.1.4          R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0    backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2       
[11] evaluate_0.17       httr_1.4.4          pillar_1.9.0        rlang_1.1.1         googlesheets4_1.0.1
[16] curl_4.3.3          readxl_1.4.1        rstudioapi_0.14     data.table_1.14.6   rmarkdown_2.17     
[21] googledrive_2.0.0   foreign_0.8-83      munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.1         compiler_4.2.2     
[26] modelr_0.1.9        xfun_0.34           base64enc_0.1-3     pkgconfig_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.3    
[31] tidyselect_1.2.0    fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.4.0          dbplyr_2.2.1       
[36] withr_2.5.0         grid_4.2.2          jsonlite_1.8.3      gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3    
[41] DBI_1.1.3           pacman_0.5.1        scales_1.2.1        zip_2.2.2           cli_3.6.1          
[46] stringi_1.7.8       fs_1.5.2            snakecase_0.11.0    xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2     
[51] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.6.2         openxlsx_4.2.5.1    tools_4.2.2         glue_1.6.2         
[56] hms_1.1.2           fastmap_1.1.0       yaml_2.3.6          colorspace_2.0-3    gargle_1.2.1       
[61] rvest_1.0.3         knitr_1.40          haven_2.5.1


Have you tried updating Rstudio?

It sounds like maybe RStudio thinks you are working in a different programming language. I know option+"-" returns a "=" when working in a python script. What else is in the file you are editing? Have you tried choosing File...New File...R Script to make sure it happens in new files as well?
